# How to generate setup (.msi or exe) file with the CI build in Azure Devops?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, setup-project

I have created a new setup project using VS Installer extension on my VS2019 for .Net windows application.
The setup is getting created well on the local machine and I'm able to install the setup on application server  .
But when I check-in the setup project only setup.vdproj file is appearing in the repository on Azure DevOps   .
I want setup to be generated in Azure DevOps too , So that I can download the setup from Azure DevOps only .
Please let me know what actually I need to do to make sure that setup is also created on Azure DevOps(or it's build server)   . I'm attaching a screenshot of CI,Release build Pipeline .
Thanks in Advance !
[image: setup is not appearing here]
[image: CI pipeline]
[image: Release pipeline]

[image: build error]

[image: updated build]

Answer (score 1):

You have to [configure your own build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) to run the build since Visual Studio Installer Projects extension is not installed on the Microsoft-Hosted Agent.

Make sure the VS Installer Projects extension is installed on your own build agent machine and then you can build the setup project using command line task with `devenv` command.

[image]

Comment: I have added a Command Line task in my build pipeline .

Comment: Hi , I have added the Command Line  : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv" in my pipeline , perhaps this task is taking too long to run . I have queued a build and this task is still in progress for lat 30 minutes . Can you please tell me what's the right of write the command in order to just build the Setup project only ?

Comment: Have you configured a self-hosted build agent? Check my updated screenshot.

Comment: Hi , I have added two screenshots in my initial post  . I have updated the build and i am getting error at command line  .The command line continue running for 59 min . I have installed Vs installer extension in VS present on build agent server  .Also tried by download and unzip from : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Comment: Can you please guide what could possibly be causing the issue here  . Another thing I found strange is after making this change I started getting error at 'Build' task even though there's no changes involved in repo . Looking forward for your response .

Comment: Hi Cece ,Can I have your comment here ?