# Building MSI in azure devops

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, windows-installer

We have for a while been building various web projects with AzureDevops and self hosted build agents.

Today I had to add a new build, consisting of a windows service written in .net core 3.1. This service has to be installed by our customers, so we have to provide it in a friendly installable way. As some of our developers were already used to handle MSI/*.vdproj projects, they added a vdproj into the *.sln to manage that. On a developper machine, this is not a problem even with VS2019: you just have to use [the relevant VS studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)...

But when it comes to building that in a CI/CD context, this becomes a real challenge. I quickly understood that [we can't use MSBuild](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/6e213531-9d88-43ef-8262-fe0e4e7f479a/msbuild-for-vdproj?forum=msbuild) at all for that and found some alternative using directly Visual Studio (devenv)... Inspired by [this thread (still opened)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498975/how-to-generate-setup-msi-or-exe-file-with-the-ci-build-in-azure-devops), I came up with the following command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv" [...]\MySolution.sln /build "Release" /Project MyInstallationProject
```

This worked fine both  on my developer machine and even on the build agent machine. But when I add it into a build pipeline as a command line task, it seems to hang, and after a while I get the following result for the job:

```
##[error]The job running on agent <MyAgent> ran longer than the maximum time of 60 minutes. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077134
```

What can I do to make it work?

What are the best practices for generating a self installable in a CI/CD context? (Is MSI still relevant? )

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try to install the extension [Build VS Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.BuildInstaller) and use the task DutchWorkz - Build VS Installer(s) to build Visual Studio Installer Project in Azure Pipelines.

[image]

Here are some tickets([ticket1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999640/how-to-build-setup-project-from-vdproj-in-azure-devops), [ticket2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630699/vsts-build-is-not-generating-msi-file-using-vdproj/54686694?noredirect=1#comment96605611_54686694)) with similar issue you can refer to.

Comment: No longer an option: `"This extension is now unpublished from Marketplace."` :(